# Change JS code in order to work with GTM (arrow function and spread expression)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-tag-manager

I use this JS code to get title value from `a` elements in a series of `li` :

```
var res = [...document.querySelectorAll(".breadcrumb li:not(:first-of-type) > a")].map(el => el.getAttribute("title")).join(" - ");
alert(res)
```

I have to use it in Google Tag Manager but it doesn't work because GTM doesn't support ECMASCRIPT6.

How arrow function and spread expression can be changed to make it works with tag manager?

Comment: something like ..... `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(...)).map(function(el){ return el})` ??

Comment: Try Babel online. https://babeljs.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `Array.prototype.slice` on the `NodeList` to convert to an array. The arrow function can just be replaced with a regular function:

```
var res = []
  .slice
  .call(document.querySelectorAll(".breadcrumb li:not(:first-of-type) > a"))
  .map(function (el) {
    return el.getAttribute('title')
  })
  .join(' - ')
```